# Is the Cache Index the same for each Cache block/line?

Tags: caching, assembly, mips, processor

From what I could find online, the Cache index is the same for every cache block/line. The notes that our instructor gave us seem to contradict this.

[image: picture of the notes page]

Comment: The bits indexes are the same but, of course, the final value depends on the address accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Cache index ( or some times called `set bits`) are the (block address) module (number of blocks in the cache).

If the number of entries in the cache is a power of 2, then modulo can be
computed simply by using the low-order log2 (cache size in blocks) bits of the
address.

In your case direct mapped cache.

A 4-block cache uses the two lowest bits (4 = 2^2 ) of the block
address.

```
(block address)       cache index
   0000 mod 4     =       00
   1000 mod 4     =       00
   0000 mod 4     =       00
   0110 mod 4     =       10
   1000 mod 4     =       00
```

---

Here are some equations and parameter that is good to know in order to solve cache problems in general.

**Parameter to know**

```
C = cache capacity
b = block size
B = number of blocks
N = degree of associativity
S = number of set
tag_bits
set_bits (also called index)
byte_offset
v = valid bits
```

**Equations to know**

```
B = C/b
S = B/N
b = 2^(byte_offset)
S = 2^(set_bits)
```

**Memory Address**

```
|___tag________|____set___|___byte offset_|
```